# Jersey RESTful Service, Error 500

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, netbeans-6.9

I am new to Restful web services. I want to access the Server via a Jersey Client. But I am getting a 500 error. What i am trying to do is submit an table name through the client end and retrieve the table contents as a JSON. Can anyone please find the error here?

This is my client end

```
 public JSONObject loadTable(String tablename) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    pathParams.add("tablename", tablename);
    JSONObject jsontable = service.path("access").path("loadtable").queryParams(pathParams).get(JSONObject.class);
    return jsontable;
}
```

This is my Server end

```
@Path("/loadtable")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public JSONObject loadTable(@QueryParam("tablename") String tablename) throws Exception {
    List<Pricing> pricing = new ArrayList<Pricing>();
    try {
        query = c.prepareStatement("select * from '" + tablename + "'");
        ResultSet ets_rs = query.executeQuery();

        while (ets_rs.next()) {
            pricing.add(new Pricing(ets_rs.getString(1), ets_rs.getString(2),  ets_rs.getString(3), ets_rs.getString(4), ets_rs.getString(5), ets_rs.getString(6)));
        }
        query.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    }
    JSONObject jsonTable = JsonConvert.getJsonFromPricing(pricing);
    System.out.println(jsonTable);
    return jsonTable;
}
```

The Pricing class in the Server end converts the Result set to a JSON.

This is the StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET http://localhost:8080/ServerETS/resources/access/loadtable?tablename=prices returned a response status of 500
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:563)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:179)
    at Link.ClientLink.loadTable(ClientLink.java:60)
    at Interfaces.Pricing.loadTable(Pricing.java:112)
    at Interfaces.Pricing.<init>(Pricing.java:32)
    at Interfaces.MainMenu.panelPricing(MainMenu.java:1026)
    at Interfaces.AdminData.btnAdminDataOKActionPerformed(AdminData.java:150)
    at Interfaces.AdminData.access$000(AdminData.java:26)
    at Interfaces.AdminData$1.actionPerformed(AdminData.java:70)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6288)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

And this is the GlassFish Server Log

```
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class org.json.simple.JSONObject, and Java type class org.json.simple.JSONObject, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Please include more details. What is the stacktrace?

Comment: Can you provide also server log (there should be also an exception explaining what caused the HTTP 500)?

Comment: @LutzHorn I have included the Stacktrace.

Comment: @MichalGajdos I have included the server log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the Client End as follows

```
public String loadTable(String tablename) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    pathParams.add("tablename", tablename);
    ClientResponse response = service.path("access").path("loadtable").queryParams(pathParams).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);
    String responseString = response.getEntity(String.class);
    return responseString;
}
```

and the server end as follows,

```
@Path("/loadtable")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Pricing> loadTable(@QueryParam("tablename") String tablename) throws Exception {
    List<Pricing> pricing = new ArrayList<Pricing>();
    try {
        query = c.prepareStatement("select * from " + tablename);
        ResultSet ets_rs = query.executeQuery();

        while (ets_rs.next()) {
            pricing.add(new Pricing(ets_rs.getString(1), ets_rs.getString(2),  ets_rs.getString(3), ets_rs.getString(4), ets_rs.getString(5), ets_rs.getString(6)));
        }
        query.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    }
    return pricing;
}
```

And Annotated Pricing with JAXB @XmlRootElement...
worked like magic!
Thanks @LutzHorn for the comments!

Answer (score 2):

Jersey can't serialize your response of a `JSONObject` to JSON. Change your method to something like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response loadTable(@QueryParam("tablename") String tablename) throws Exception {
  // ...
  Pricing pricing = ...
  return Response.ok(pricing).build();
}
```

Annotate `Pricing` with JAXB `@XmlRootElement` and let JAXB do the conversion to JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I am still getting the same error. When I add an s.out below the "loadtable" method header it does not give any result. So i guess the error is in the client side method call or the server side "loadtable" method header.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to send the request data as JSON format, you may modify the MIME type of server consumed data type to JSON type:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Comment: @tonga... Actually my input is not in JSON format. It's Plain Text. Only my output is JSON.